# Cancel in-process hibernation from event service

Tags: dual-boot, services, hibernate

I have the following custom service running at hibernation:

```
[Unit]
Description=Unmount shared DATA partition *BEFORE* hibernate and hybrid-sleep
Before=hybrid-sleep.target
Before=hibernate.target
#Before=suspend.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/me/bin/unmount-partition.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
WantedBy=hibernate.target
#WantedBy=suspend.target
```

Basically, once a hibernation command is issued, my custom service is triggered, and in turn, it executes a custom script where I do some tidying and I try to dismount a shared NTFS partition (for dual boot with Windows). I use the following commands in my script for that purpose:

```
fsuuid=ABCDEF # UUID
device=$(blkid -U "$fsuuid")

if ! df | grep -q $device ; then
    # Parition not found.. Already dismounted?
    # Do some stuff...
    exit 0
else
    cd ~
    if umount UUID=$fsuuid ; then
        # Parition successfully dismounted
        # Do some stuff...
        exit 0
    else
        # *** Disk is busy; abort hibernation here!! ***
        exit 1
    fi
fi
```

What I'm seeking is a way to abort the in-progress hibernation process from within the execution flow of my script when the dismounting fails (busy disk for example). Is that doable or is issuing a conditional hibernation command from within my script itself (whilst ditching the even-triggered service) my only option?